# django filer no module named fields.image error

Tags: python, django

I have this problem. I have installed filer and when I import only filer its fine `import filer`
 It is importing but when I do `from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField`

It is not importing and gives error no module named fields.image

What is the problem? I have gone through the documentation and it gives the same way of importing.

Comment: Do you have a python file or module called `filer` (`filer.py` in case of a file) in your current directory that would shadow the `filer` package?

Comment: dude I have installed filer.. python package..

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but I wondered if you had a Python file called `filer.py` that could be imported instead of the `filer` package. When you import `filer`, what is the result of `dir(filer)`?

Comment: No I dont have any filer.py

Comment: Ok, when you import `filer`, do you have access to `filer.fields.image.FilerImageField`?

Comment: see when I do import filer its importing and when I do from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField its giving error.. I dont know what you are saying.. Its just not importing the fields.image... no module named fields.image

Comment: Could you post the result of `import filer` then `filer.__file__`?

Comment: 'filer/__init__.pyc'  this is the result after running import filer then filer.__file__

Comment: My guess is that you have a folder called `filer` in your current directory (or somewhere in your `PYTHON_PATH`) which contains a `__init__.py` file which makes it a Python module, it gets imported instead of the `filer` package that you installed.

Comment: yeah I have made a filer folder for css and javascripts.. so what.. what to do now

Comment: I find your tone disrespectful. I would review what it looks like to [Be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Charlie Well I am sorry that you had that impression, may I ask what exactly gave it to you?

Comment: Sorry I was replying to @aryan in reference to saying "dude I have installed filer." and "yeah I have made a filer folder for css and javascripts.. so what."

Comment: sorry if it was that but my intention was not to direspect.. :)

Comment: I have filer folder but I dont have __init__.py file in it to make module. So why it is acting as module ? It should import filer labrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a Python file called `filer.py` or a Python module (folder containing a `__init__.py` file) called `filer` in your current directory (or somewhere in your `PYTHON_PATH`) which shadows the `filer` package you installed.

You need to remove or rename that file/module in order to be able to use the `filer` package.